# Opening an xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, linux, file

I've extracted an excel file by running the code below.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
with ZipFile('HISTDATA_COM_XLSX_EURUSD_M12018.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
   zipObj.extractall()
```

After that, I wanted to open it. Due to being an xlsx file, I imported the openpyxl module and ran the code below.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import openpyxl

with ZipFile('HISTDATA_COM_XLSX_EURUSD_M12018.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
    zipObj.extractall()

ref_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('DAT_XLSX_EURUSD_M1_2018.xlsx')
```

Then, I received this error:
"Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl’s default in Python."
So I also imported the warnings module and ran the code below:

```
import warnings
from zipfile import ZipFile
import openpyxl

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

with ZipFile('HISTDATA_COM_XLSX_EURUSD_M12018.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
    zipObj.extractall()

ref_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('DAT_XLSX_EURUSD_M1_2018.xlsx')
```

But I received nothing in the output. Can anyone help?
My operating system is Linux Ubuntu.
The link of the file which I downloaded and extracted is: https://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/excel/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2018

P.S! I don't want to use the pandas module.

Comment: what you want with this document ?do you want the data ?

Comment: Because you can use pandas to read all data file .

Comment: I just want to practice extracting and opening an excel file. I also don't want to use pandas module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does appear to be returning a reference to a workbook, but you're not reading any data from it. You need to specify a sheet and read data from cells.

```
import warnings
from zipfile import ZipFile
import openpyxl

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

with ZipFile('HISTDATA_COM_XLSX_EURUSD_M12018.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
    zipObj.extractall()

ref_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('DAT_XLSX_EURUSD_M1_2018.xlsx')

sheet_2018 = ref_workbook['2018']
cell_A1 = sheet_2018['A1'].value
print(cell_A1)

cell_A1 = sheet_2018.cell(1, 1).value
print(cell_A1)
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01 17:00:00
2018-01-01 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyautogui to open files

```
from os import path
import pyautogui

filename = pyautogui.prompt("Filename: ")
print("Exists File: %s " % path.isfile(filename))
f = open(filename, "r")
```

You can use pyautogui to open files

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** when I set `data_only=True` I was able to read the workbook without the error. Also, you have to tell it to use the active worksheet, like so...

```
ref_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('DAT_XLSX_EURUSD_M1_2018.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws = ref_workbook.active #per the docs
```

The source code for the `load_workbook` function mentions a `data_only` argument. Considering its a simple dataset with no formatting in the original xlsx, my guess is that may help.

Source for `load_workbook`:
https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.0/openpyxl/reader/excel.py#L288